# The usage of "doing all this waiting" & "at the bone"

Tags: prepositions, phrase-usage, sarcasm

> A: Remember, we don't have to deliver every last inch of the man,
>   Brian
>
> B: You got a good point there, Ronnie
>
> A: Lend me your knife.
>
> B: Should I take a nap while I'm **doing all this waiting**?
>
> A: I'm **at the bone**, all right? There we go. Have you ever seen
>   anything so pretty in your whole life?
>
> -- Sin City 2005

The scary scene occurs when A is cutting the dead man's head off while B is complaining of A's inefficiency.

I'm wondering if **doing all this waiting** is an idiom. Can I use **having all this waiting** or **taking all this waiting** instead?

Besides, why **at the bone**? I know he is saying his knife has reached the bone. Why is **at** used? I would use **to the bone** or **on the bone**. Is it the same **at** as in *at home* or *at school*?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, *doing all this waiting* is not an idiom, but the construction is unusual in American English (the dialect of the movie, though the characters in question supposedly speak British English, as they're Irish). The men in this scene have been hired to quickly deliver proof that the man they're cutting up is dead, and B is sarcastically implying that performing the act of waiting has become a necessary step in this process when they ought not to be waiting at all. He's expressing his impatience with A.

*All this waiting* is an action being performed here, and B quips that he could be doing something else at the same time (*taking a nap*). It is not correct to use *having* or *taking* in place of *doing* here, because we use *doing* in the general case of performing an action. We don't *take a wait* or *have waits*, because waiting is not something that we frequently describe as being possessed, gained or received.

Here's an example. Imagine a man working in an office, filling out reports. He's extremely busy and behind schedule. There's a huge pile of papers on his desk. His coworker, who also has a lot to do, comes in and asks the man to cover for him while he goes out to run an errand. The man looks up and says incredulously:

> You want me to *take* all your calls while I'm *doing* all this paperwork?

He *takes* (i.e. receives) calls, but *does* (fills out or completes) paperwork.

In the case of *at the bone*, A is describing the progress of his knife through the corpse's neck. It has *arrived at* the bone. *To the bone* marks the bone as the knife's destination, which it isn't. *On the bone* suggests a more lengthy action than is the case here. The intent is to cut through the bone quickly, not let the knife rest on it. If he had said *I'm cutting on the bone*, it would mean his knife is striking the bone but not effectively or efficaciously going through it, so it won't be cut apart any time soon.

Comment: By the same token, I remember we can use "have a swim", which I think is not a thing which be possessed.

Comment: You're absolutely right that the possession guidelines don't cover every case. The same sense for *swim* applies to *run*, *rest* or *nap*. Here *take* and *have* express intention (*take* does so more strongly) to cause oneself (but not someone else; you don't *give* a swim) to undergo a significant change in state (becoming quickly moving, asleep or underwater) for some expressed purpose (fitness, pleasure or becoming rested). Really though, the most correct answer is, somewhat unfortunately, *this is just how we do it; English is funny like that*.

Comment: Additionally, these are discrete activities; they have clear beginnings and endings, and are relatively short. You might say we metaphorically "possess" or "acquire" the states they represent or, less metaphorically, their effects on us (which generally last significantly longer than the activity itself).

Comment: Your guideline is fine. At least I don't have to learn by rote. Thx!

Answer (score 3):

There's nothing specifically idiomatic about *doing all this waiting*. It's actually two pretty stock expressions, [doing][all this X]. The  *doing* part is the stock 'light' *do*, a sort of generic verb or pro-verb.

> What are you doing?
>   I'm doing a lot of nothing.
>   I'm doing whatever strikes my fancy.

So, No, you can't substitute *have* or *take* - they're too specific, and they don't form ordinary idiomatic expressions with *waiting*.

The *all this X* part is an expression of annoyance - it implies that there is a great deal more *X* than you care for. *X* is very often a gerund.

> What are we going to do with all this ugly carpet?
>   I'm tired of all this arguing.
>   All this shilly-shallying is getting us nowhere.

And *at* would be in the sense *I've arrived **at** the bone*. He is reporting his progress.

Comment: Can I use *on*, meaning "touching"?

Comment: @ZhanlongZheng Esoteric Screen Name addresses that question very nicely.

Comment: Why did you employ present simple tense in "E.S.N addresses that question very nicely"? It's not in a story-telling or explanatory context. I would expect "E.S.N addressed that question very nicely".

Comment: @KinzleB I am citing a text that is still "present" to our eyes. This is conventional in my field, LitCrit: unless we are explicitly placing a work in historical context, we cast quotations from Shakespeare or Virginia Wolf or  other critics in the present tense.